# Solving equation of motion with exponential friction term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

My friend's kid asked me this question. I have no idea how to solve it since I have stopped calculating mechanics for about 15 years since I graduated from high school.

The question is:
A boat that has mass $m$ and initial velocity $v_0$ moves along the $\mathrm{x}$-direction. It is slowed by a friction force $F=-a\cdot e^{b\cdot v}$, where $a,b$ are positive constants, $v$ is the velocity of the boat. Determine **a)** the motion of the boat, **b)** the stopping distance.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes. That could do it. But I hope you can provide some details of how you obtain the expressions of the displacement and velocity. You don't need to show how you numerically solve the equation. I can manage the equation solving part. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation is not complicated and has an analytical solution.
Using $F=ma$ you get $m\frac{dv}{dt}=-a\cdot e^{b\cdot v}$, move both  dt and the exponential to the opposite side and you get the solution for $v$ after integration of a simple exponential. 
Repeat using $v(t)=dx/dt$
 to get the distance

Comment: You are right. I took me less than a minute to have Wolfram alpha calculate the solution for me. Man, I have become so lazy!

Comment: @CuriousOne: at least you're not as lazy as calling anything "nontrivial" if it's not immediately solved by Fourier transform, and proposing to do it numerically...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Do they accept a link to a Wolfram alpha calculation in undergrad physics, these days? If not, I may be in trouble, if I had to fulfill the requirements for my degree, again... :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one force to consider, the friction force.  So you use Newton's 2nd law to write the equation of motion, remembering the relationship between velocity and acceleration.

The rest is just solving that differential equation for the velocity, which can be done numerically, or by looking it up in a table, or with math software.

Once you have that you can solve for the stopping time and integrate the velocity to find the stopping distance.